# Show file/line from a "[timestamp] TypeError: .."

Tags: node.js, logging, forever

Sometimes my API in node.js throws a (for example)

```
// Forever error log
[2015-05-20 08:07:48] TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

As you see, I don't have a clue where it comes from, Is there any way to get that information?

Comment: This error seems to be caught and printed by a logging library, which may be the reason why the exception stack-trace is not shown.

Comment: It's from 'Forever' module but I can't find a way to get that info :/

Comment: I would recommand looking into forever's documentation, sorry I can't help more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed adding an Error handler to my app.js

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
    // Log the error as you want
    log(err.stack || err.message, 'error');
});
```

For more info about error handling with expressjs: http://expressjs.com/guide/error-handling.html